# Qt convert QTextEdit HTML to QByteArray

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

I have a QTextEdit where text can be inserted as html. This text needs to be sent over a QTcpSocket.

I retrieve the text from the QTextEdit as follows:

```
  QString text = ui->message->toPlainText();
  socket->write(text.toLatin1().data());
```

This works well for text without HTML, but otherwise I get just `??` for it. 
Is there another possibility to transform the text or do I have to chose a completely different approach?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, just have to use

```
  text.toUtf8()
```

instead

Comment: Be sure, that other application will read your byte array from socket as utf8

Comment: I'm reading it with `QString msg; msg.append(socket->readAll());` and that works fine

Comment: Ok, but there is a good class for serialization / deserialization: `QDataStream`. And you should use `QString::fromUtf8( socket-readAll() );`